# How to catch someone's Ip Address through twitter direct messages?

Tags: twitter, location, ip, ip-address, message

am sorry guys for this question its not related to any programming issue but there was someone who disturb me for a while on twitter actually for 7 month and i haven't blocked him until now cause i want to know who is he or she yes am a little bit curious so if he or she send me a direct message again on twitter can I then get his or her IP-Address after that can I know who is him specifically  . I have been trying to know him for that long time but with no result so could anyone help me if yes I'll appreciate it and If no there is no problem and thanks

Comment: And what would you do once you have his/hers IP address? Just block the person and problem solved.

Comment: no i will let him no that i have found him so he or she wouldn't disturb anybody else and am not going to block him or her

Comment: Clearly didn't catch the sarcasm in my question. An IP address means nothing to be honest. I doubt you'll ever be able to find out who it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. No, this is not possible.
2. Even if it were, there is no reliable way to link an IP address to a person.

Comment: yeah I know this but if I know the IP I can know who is him by his location am I right ?

Comment: Not without being able to get records from his internet service provider.  IP addresses often change over time, and there are other factors that can further cloud the issue (e.g. proxy servers).  Just block him and be done with it.